# raspistill is not working on Raspberry 4 Model B with Raspberry OS Buster and Pi Camera rev 1.3 (supposedly OV5647)

Tags: camera, raspbian-buster

I have confirmed that it is detected by vcgencmd and v4l2-ctl

vcgen:

```
$ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1, libcamera interfaces=0
```

v4l2-ctl:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
bcm2835-codec-decode (platform:bcm2835-codec):
    /dev/video10
    /dev/video11
    /dev/video12
    /dev/video18
    /dev/video31

bcm2835-isp (platform:bcm2835-isp):
    /dev/video13
    /dev/video14
    /dev/video15
    /dev/video16
    /dev/video20
    /dev/video21
    /dev/video22
    /dev/video23

mmal service 16.1 (platform:bcm2835-v4l2-0):
    /dev/video0

$ v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --list-formats-ex
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'YU12' (Planar YUV 4:2:0)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [2]: 'RGB3' (24-bit RGB 8-8-8)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [3]: 'JPEG' (JFIF JPEG, compressed)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [4]: 'H264' (H.264, compressed)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [5]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [6]: 'YVYU' (YVYU 4:2:2)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [7]: 'VYUY' (VYUY 4:2:2)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [8]: 'UYVY' (UYVY 4:2:2)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [9]: 'NV12' (Y/CbCr 4:2:0)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [10]: 'BGR3' (24-bit BGR 8-8-8)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [11]: 'YV12' (Planar YVU 4:2:0)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [12]: 'NV21' (Y/CrCb 4:2:0)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
    [13]: 'RX24' (32-bit XBGR 8-8-8-8)
            Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 1920x1080 with step 2/2
```

However, raspistill is still giving error:

```
$ raspistill -o test.jpg -v

"raspistill" Camera App (commit 8fa944c74085 Tainted)

Camera Name toshh2c
Width 1920, Height 1080, filename test.jpg
Using camera 0, sensor mode 0

GPS output Disabled

Quality 85, Raw no
Thumbnail enabled Yes, width 64, height 48, quality 35
Time delay 5000, Timelapse 0
Link to latest frame enabled  no
Full resolution preview No
Capture method : Single capture

Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
Preview window 0,0,1024,768
Opacity 255
Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
Flicker Avoid Mode 'off'
Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V = 128
Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

I run this on a fresh install so I am sure there's no other program using the camera.

I use Raspberry 4 Model B with Raspberry OS Buster and Pi Camera rev 1.3 (supposedly OV5647)

What is wrong with my setup? Why is it not working? As a side note: the LED on my camera is not blinking on startup and on raspistill command. Is it possible that the pins are different than the previous models?

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: @RostyslavKinash no, I guess it was the raspi that was the old revision, not the latest. Or maybe I fried some circuit when trying out other modules (an oled display that I hooked up wrong, vcc and gnd reversed). Changing raspi fixed the problem.